# How to set dynamic markup to a transformation wrapper in Kentico

Tags: asp.net, ascx, kentico

I'm very new to Kentico and asp, I'm coming from a php/Wordpress background into this.  I'm working on a Page Template that has an optional Carousel in it.  I'll need the content of the carousel which I have set as a Document Type, but I'd also like to be able to have a Settings Document type in which they are contained.  In the Settings Document Type I want to be able to control what kind of wrapper goes around the whole thing, using a form to do this.  I've played around with Hierarchical Transformations, but can't seem to get them to work.  At best, I'm able to display markup from the transformation, but the variables set in the Settings Form won't to come through.

Does anyone have any idea as to the best way to get this to work the way I want it to, or is this even possible?  I only have access to the CMS and have no access to the file structure or anything like that.  I've looked through pages of Kentico documentation, but it seems vague and I can't seem to find any examples of anything close to what I want to achieve.

Update:  I've finally somewhat figured out how to make this work with Hierarchical Transformations, but I'm still having an issue with the Opening and Closing Wrappers which I set as Header and Footer Transformations.  For some reason these tags appear twice, one within the other.  The outer one does exactly what it's supposed to do, but the inner one doesn't take the variables set within the form.  Anyone have any idea how I can just display this once?